# Jinja2 api: how to get the inherited template of a template?

Tags: python, jinja2

A template file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

The templates are loaded like the following:

```
env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader(['_templates']))
template = env.get_template('test.html')
```

How can I get the parent template object, i.e., the template of "base.html", from the `template` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse template source and find `Extends` node. See [AST documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#ast) for details

```
from jinja2.nodes import Extends

env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader(['_templates']))
template_source = env.loader.get_source(env, 'test.html')[0]
parsed_template = env.parse(template_source)
extends_node = parsed_template.find(Extends)
parent_name = extends_node.template.value
parent_template = env.get_template(parent_name)
```